# Find ages of two persons, with information about today and a certain moment in the past.

Tags: linear-algebra

The sum of the present ages of Erick and Henry is $55$. When Henry was same old as Erick's present age, Erick was $20$. What is Henry's present age?

I'm still thinking on it. Let me show what I thought

$$E + H = 55 \tag{1}$$

$$H -t = E \tag{2}$$

$$E -t = 20 \tag{3}$$

where $t = \text {passed time}$, $E = \text{Erick}$, $H = \text{Henry}$

I've gone too wrong, haven't I?

Comment: nope, you seems on the right track. solve for t.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace your title (which was not a title but a repetition of the question) by a more significant one.

Comment: I can't get an integer value from these equations even if I'm solving them for the variable $t$.

Comment: @JeanMarie am grateful, thank you.

Comment: $(2)-(3) $ will give a usefull equation.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Let me take a look at it again.

Comment: H=30; E=25, t=5, all seems good to me.

Comment: @Mefitico How you got that? this is what I'm struggling with. Then I've to train more algebra lol.

Comment: Finally, I've got $2E+t = 55 \implies 40 + 3t = 55 \implies 3t = 15 \implies t = 5$.

Comment: "I've gone too wrong, haven't I?"  Why do you think that.  Seems perfectly correct to me.

Comment: The next step you shall do, is to arrange the three unknowns ($E,H,t$) to the left and in order, while putting on the right the given data: that will help you to visually catch the steps that you may take (substitution, row combinations, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems good to me.

Three linear equations with three unknown variables.  Should be solvable if they aren't dependent which they clearly aren't.

So try to solve them.

.... go ahead.  Solve them... My solution is below but you should try solving them first.

One way: $H = E + t$ so substitute that back into the first to get $E + H = E+(E+t) = 2E + t = 55$.  Add that to the last equation to get $(2E+t) +(E-t) = 55 + 20$ or $3E = 75$.  So $E = 25$.

Plug that in and we get $25 + H = 55$ and $H - t = 25$ and $25 -t = 20$.  From there is clear $H = 30$ and $t= 5$ and.... sure enough.  Eric is $25$ and Henry is $30$ and $5$ years ago when Henry was $25$, Eric was $20$.

Answer (score 0):

Solving for one variable then using the result to solve for the others will give you the correct results. Here I solve for t

$(1)$  $E+H=55$

$(2)$  $H-t=E$  $->$ $H=E+t$

$(3)$  $E-t=20$  $->$ $E=20+t$

Adding $(2)$ and $(3)$, will isolate H.

$H+E=E+2t+20$

$H=20+2t$

Substituting $(2)+(3)$ and $(3)$ in $(1)$, will give the value of t.

$20+t+20+2t=55$

$t=5$

Now the rest can be calculated fairly easily.